# Add View to View Pager Manually

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have a viewPager. I have no problem with adding items if model.size()!=0

```
  public void BindToViewPager(ArrayList<ModelWeather> model){

  if(model.size() != 0) 
        {
            SliderAdapter slAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this, model);
            viewPager.setAdapter(slAdapter);
        }

        else
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_error_item, null);
            viewPager.addView(view);
        }
```

When model.size() == 0 i try to add RelativeLayout to viewPager by addView method but it adds nothing.

Here is R.layout.slider_error_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Sorry, there is no data."
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the view to the adapter rather than directly to the viewpager.